# Upgrading Apache on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, apache, mod-security2

I am currently running Apache 2.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I would like to upgrade Apache to version 2.4.9 so that I can run mod_security2. I installed Apache 2.2 via an installer. I don't, however, see an installer for Apache v2.4.9. I can find the full Apache Windows binaries on ApacheLounge. I'm just not clear on how to seamlessly upgrade to version 2.4.9. Here's what I'm thinking of doing:

- download version 2.4.9 Windows binaries from ApacheLounge
- stop Apache 2.2 service
- rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2 to Apache2.2_OLD
- create Apache2.4 folder at C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\
- copy contents of downloaded Windows binaries to Apache2.4 folder
- set up httpd.exe within the Apache2.4\bin folder as a Windows service
- copy httpd.conf file from Apache2.2\conf over to Apache2.4\conf
- modify httpd.conf file to point to new Apache installation location
- copy any modules from Apache\modules that are missing (and needed) from Apache2.4\modules
- start Apache2.4 Windows service

Am I over-simplifying? What steps are missing? I'm relatively new to Apache, so it's possible I'm overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Update: I, more or less, followed the steps above and it worked. some of the modules I had in v2.2, like mod_wsgi and mod_security2, needed to be upgraded to work with v2.4. There are also a few directives that have been deprecated that can either be replaced or you can use mod_access_compat.   Here's a good reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html